# ESLint in VSCode not fixing on save

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code, lint

I am using ESLint in my Vue(Nuxt) project in VSCode. When I save I would like my ESLint to run automatically and fix all the warnings for me automatically.

This is my settings.json file in VSCode:

```
{
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "vscode-typescript",
    "vetur.validation.template": false,
    "vetur.completion.scaffoldSnippetSources": {},
    "vetur.completion.useScaffoldSnippets": false,
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "none",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.defaultCloneDirectory": "",
    "gitlens.views.repositories.files.layout": "list",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
}
```

And this is my .eslintrc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "@nuxtjs",
    "plugin:nuxt/recommended",
    "../.eslintrc.js"
  ],
  rules: {
    //Add custom rules for the frontend here.
    //Rules that are common for shared, frontend and backend should go in the parent file
    "nuxt/no-cjs-in-config": "off",
  },
}
```

The linked ../.eslintrc.js file contains the following:

```
module.exports = {
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
  plugins: ['jest'],
  rules: {
    'prefer-const': 'off',
    'comma-dangle': ['error', 'always-multiline'],
    'prefer-template': 'error',
  },
  env: {
    'jest/globals': true
  }
}
```

Whenever I save the file the warnings just show up and will not automatically fix themselves. 
[image: eslint warnings]

EDIT:
I've turned on verbose output and i'm seeing this in the output:

```
(node:6832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in 'frontend\.eslintrc.js » @nuxtjs/eslint-config': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-import'
Require stack:
```

I've then ran `yarn add eslint-plugin-import` and tried again, it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 128):

Get eslint plugin, add this code to your settings.json

```
 {
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": "explicit"
  },
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript"]
 }
```

[source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/pull/1751)

Comment: .eslint is deprecated afaik, works just source.fixAll

Comment: Note that one downside of {"source.fixAll": true} is that VSCode will automatically delete any code you have that runs past a return statement. So, if you are testing, comment out the code instead of using "return"

Comment: @shackleton maybe this can be changed in lint rules

Answer (score 78):

Create the following path `.vscode/settings.json` on the root of the project directory, then paste and save the following:

```json
{
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    }
}
```

You're good to go!

Comment: For anyone using VSCodium on Ubuntu, the location of settings.json is "~/.config/VSCodium/User/settings.json"

Comment: Thanks, I was finally able to solve it with this. Thank you so much.

Comment: For anyone confused like me: This settings should be placed in projectFolder/.vscode/

Comment: why on Earth this is not coming with eslint extension settings...

Comment: eslint.validate is legacy. Release notes states: "This is an old legacy setting and should in normal cases not be necessary anymore." https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint

Answer (score 44):

I've managed to fix the issue.
The problem was that there were multiple working directories in my solution, which all have their own eslint config.
Putting the following line in the settings.json file of VSCode solved my issue:

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }]
```

Comment: Would be good to understand why this is necessary, as I haven't seen this anywhere else.

Comment: Another option is `[{"pattern": "./packages/*/"}]`. This is for people who use a monorepo layout through yarn workspaces or lerna. For more options see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint#settings-options

Answer (score 28):

I tried those solutions and others, and it still didn't work. Actually it was just that ESLint's use had to be approved for use in VSCode. That is, I clicked on the ESLint item on the editor's bottom bar:

[image]

Which opened a popup asking me to approve ESLint. After approval autocorrect was running as expected.

Comment: I don't have those ticks next to the "ESLint" text and not sure if I allowed the extension or not. Is there a way to check if the extension is approved? Or how can I allow it?

Answer (score 20):

I ran into a similar problem-- ESLint was not properly formatting only certain, seemingly random, files on save. Running ESLint `--fix` would fix the formatting errors, but saving would not. Adding this line to our workspace settings.json fixed the problem:

```
"eslint.format.enable": true,
```

Making all our formatter settings look like this:

```
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
  "eslint.format.enable": true,
```

You can also go into the ESLint extension settings and check off the checkbox labeled `ESLint > Format:Enable`. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 16):

Install ESLint extension from the VSCode marketplace.

Once the ESLint extension has installed you may use `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P` to open the Command Palette. Search “ESLint fix all auto-fixable Problems” and press enter.

This command would enable eslint to fix the file on save.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've tried that out, and a info window in the bottom right is showing up giving me the following message:
"Failed to apply ESLint fixes to the document. Please consider opening an issue with steps to reproduce."

Comment: I've added extra info in my original question after seeing the verbose output.

Comment: What do you mean this option should be enabled? `ESLint fix all auto-fixable Problems` is not an option, it's an action.

Comment: for mac its CMD+SHIFT+P

Comment: This just fixes it once. The OP wanted to know how to fix it on save.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

In the snap above as you can see that I am getting eslint errors and just to inform you all that **despite saving the file, all auto-fixable problems are were not getting fixed by eslint/prettier setup.**

So I tried pressing ctrl+shift+p and selecting prettier as default formatter and also tried doing eslint restart server but that didn't worked.

I noticed that vscode was giving me some notifications at the **bottom right corner (bell icon)**. I clicked on that and some list of pop up came up stating that there are multiple formatters installed for the same extension file. Like for example in the below snap there is .jsx file(it had two formatters one was prettier and other was vscodes inbuilt formatter). I clicked on configure button and selected prettier as default and when I saved the file it worked!

[image]

If this doesn't works for you then I think this all worked for me because I had eslint npm packages installed in my project that works with prettier to enforce the prettier rules. (these packages are **eslint-config-prettier** and **eslint-plugin-prettier**)

Comment: The little bell saved my day, Thanks to you!

Answer (score 4):

What fixed it for me was adding this to `settings.json`, because VSCode didn't know what formatter I wanted to be used on save:

```
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

Check if in the settings.json there are other formatters enabled, in my case I had this by mistake.

```
"[javascript]": {
"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Open VS Code's settings

   [image]
2. Click the "Open settings (JSON)" button in the top right

   [image]
3. Add `"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }],` to the JSON file

   [image]
4. Save the file, then restart VSCode

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34513982)

Answer (score 1):

After getting the Eslint plugin you need to add this line to the settings.json:

```
{
    
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
}
```

***Still not working?*** check if your eslint works fine by running this in the terminal:

```
eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .
```

If it failed with exit code 2 try ***removing node modules and install again***.
After running this command you should see the eslint errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same issue, and nothing seemed to help, even though I did all the configurations correctly, and ESLint was marking the problems in my files correctly.

For me the solution was to **move the `.vscode` folder to the project root**.

Now everything works as intended.