# How to format JavaScript files on save in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I am trying to format my JavaScript files on save, but it is not working.

Some of the settings I am using are working & showing errors (with formatting, semi-colons, etc.) as expected:

[image]

When I save this file, I want those formatting errors to be auto-fixed.

I have tried adding `"editor.formatOnSave": true,` to `settings.json`, & restarting VS Code, but that doesn't work.

Here is my `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "eslint.validate": [
      "javascript",
      "javascriptreact",
      "json",
      "jsonc",
      "json5",
      "markdown"
    ],
    "cSpell.words": [],
    "cSpell.minWordLength": 4,
    "cSpell.showStatus": true,
    "cSpell.allowCompoundWords": true,
    "compile-hero.disable-compile-files-on-did-save-code": true,
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "blink",
    "editor.lineDecorationsWidth": "30",
    "editor.folding": false,
    "editor.hideCursorInOverviewRuler": true,
    "editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,
    "editor.roundedSelection": false,
    "editor.selectionHighlight": true,
    "editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false,
    "explorer.openEditors.visible": 0,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
    "workbench.editor.showIcons": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "workbench.tree.renderIndentGuides": "none",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "workbench.editor.highlightModifiedTabs": true,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
    "cypressHelper.menuItems.OpenCypress": false,
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active",
    "editor.guides.indentation": false,
    "cucumberautocomplete.smartSnippets": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": "cypress/support/StepDefs/*.spec.js",
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "cypress/integration/*.feature",
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": false,
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinValidation": false,
    "cucumberautocomplete.skipDocStringsFormat": false,
    "cucumberautocomplete.onTypeFormat": true,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "comments": false,
      "strings": true,
      "other": true
    },
    "conf.view.indentSymbol": "space",
    "conf.view.identsBefore.Feature": 0,
    "conf.view.identsBefore.Scenario": 2,
    "conf.view.identsBefore.Background": 2,
    "conf.view.identsBefore.ScenarioOutline": 2,
    "conf.view.identsBefore.Given": 4,
    "conf.view.identsBefore.When": 4,
    "conf.view.identsBefore.Then": 4,
    "conf.view.identsBefore.And": 4,
    "conf.view.identsBefore.Tag": "relative",
    "conf.view.identsBefore.Table": 6,
    "conf.view.identsBefore.Examples": 4,
    "conf.view.table.autoformat": true,
    "cSpell.ignoreWords": [],
    "git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,
    "[json]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": true
    }
  }
```

And here is my `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "parserOptions": {
      "requireConfigFile": false
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["*.json", "*.json5", "*.jsonc"],
        "parser": "jsonc-eslint-parser"
      }
    ],
    "rules": {
      "complexity": "off",
      "max-len":"off",
      "max-params": [2, 4],
      "max-statements":"off",
      "max-depth": "off",
      "max-nested-callbacks": "off",
      "indent": [2, 2],
      "linebreak-style": "off",
      "space-before-function-paren": [2, "always"],
      "curly": [2, "all"],
      "brace-style": [2, "1tbs"],
      "quotes": [1, "single", "avoid-escape"],
      "eqeqeq": [2, "allow-null"],
      "semi": [2, "always"],
      "new-cap": 0,
      "no-console": "off",
      "no-empty": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": 1,
      "space-before-blocks": [2, "always"],
      "keyword-spacing": [
        2,
        {
          "before": true,
          "after": true,
          "overrides": {}
        }
      ],
      "no-trailing-spaces": [
        2, {
          "skipBlankLines": false
        }
      ],
      "cypress/no-unnecessary-waiting": "off",
      "eol-last": ["error", "never"],
      "jsonc/array-bracket-newline": [
        "error",
        {
          "multiline": true,
          "minItems": null
        }
      ],
      "jsonc/object-property-newline": [
        "error", {
          "allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine": false
        }
      ],
      "jsonc/object-curly-newline": [
        "error",
        {
          "multiline": true,
          "minProperties": 1
        }
      ],
      "jsonc/array-bracket-spacing": ["error", "never"],
      "jsonc/array-element-newline": ["error", "consistent"],
      "jsonc/object-curly-spacing": 2,
      "jsonc/indent": ["error", 2, {}]
    },
  
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
  
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:jsonc/recommended-with-json"
    ]
  }
```

And here are my dependencies in `package.json`:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsonc": "^2.2.1"
  },
```

Please let me know if I can provide more info to help answer the question.

Comment: Try also editorconfig: https://editorconfig.org/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESLint in VSCode not fixing on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62277286/eslint-in-vscode-not-fixing-on-save)

Comment: @Sysix thanks for your suggestion, but I already have the solution to that question included in my `settings.json`